# How to do a Monte Carlo simulation from a fitted copula?

Tags: monte-carlo, copula

I have fitted a copula to my two data series (orange yield and orange prices). Now that I have the relationship between two variables from the copula, I need to simulate a 100 000 values from the fitted copula, but I don't know how to do that.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.